# How to place double quotation marks in PlatonScript strings

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jplaton

I need to make my jPlaton unit to return a JSON string (I use it in an AJAX call with jQuery). The proper JSON format dictates using double quotation marks to surround JSON properties. In PlatonScript strings are surrounded by double quotation marks. Since I cannot escape the double quotation marks inside PlatonScript strings, how do create a valid JSON string with double quotation marks in PlatonScript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use to use backslash () before the double quotation mark